# Windows Service Overlaps

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to learn a little more about Windows Services. I have one that runs every 15 seconds. What happens if the service is still executing when the 15 seconds are up again? Can/does the service run at the same time as itself? Can the service create a serious memory problem if too many run at the same time?

**EDIT**

So I should have been more clear: The service is running and a timer is elapsing every 15 seconds to run a set of operations. I am wondering if that timer elapses while the previous run is still executing what kind of results could happen. Should It be treated like a recursive call?

Comment: You've written 15 seconds and 15 minutes. Should they both be 15 minutes?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. A service is either running or it isn't. You can't run multiple instances of the same service at the same time (if you really are talking about a Windows service).

Comment: Are you confusing windows services and scheduled tasks?

Comment: See Edit for new information

Comment: With your update this is not related to windows services - it would affect any .Net process. I suggest you do some research on how timers work.

Comment: `Personally I would investigate the running process(es)` see where the pitfalls are and determine what other factors and or Tasks within the Spawned process are taking up `Resources` if 15 seconds is not long enough then I would truly start looking at where in the process chain are the most resources being absorbed.. also can you perhaps give a little bit more insight as to what things are being done within the 15 seconds.. then maybe you could get some more defined direction / hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution I've used when developing this kind of service is to NOT actually use a reoccurring timer.  What I do is create a single shot timer set to tick off in 15 minutes.  When the timer's proc begins I record the current time, and use that to find the running time at the end of the proc.  Using that I set another timer (or reset the same timer) to go off in 15 minutes - the amount of time the proc actually took.  If the proc takes more than 15 minutes I can adjust the timings.  This way the timers will never overlap and stack up.

Comment: He edited his question. It originally said 15 minutes.

Comment: 15 seconds, 15 minutes, 15 hours, the actual time doesn't affect the general algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

To my knowledge you would only have the one windows service running at a time and the service would perform a task periodically using a timer.

If you spawn a new thread to perform said task and there's a chance that the task would still be running when the timer triggers again then you'd want to use some sort of synchronization technique like mutexes to control access to shared resources to prevent the two threads from interfering with each other.

Alternatively you could just skip running the task if the mutex (etc) is already locked if it's not important that the task runs every 15 seconds without fail.

Comment: I don't revenge downvote. What's wrong with my answer?